# how to convert into json value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I am using rails-3

My table is countries and the fields are:

```
Id + name + created_at + updated_at
```

In my controller my query is

```
@country = Country.all
```

I want to convert my data into json. How can I do this ?

Comment: if this answer helped you, feel free to check this answer as correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@country.to_json
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

then when youre at the clientside, you can capture a request us ajax with JSON.parse(result)

Comment: @manish-nautiyal if this answer helped you, feel free to check this answer as correct :)

Comment: hit the check box and accept it as the correct answer! http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 0):

JSON (see http://www.json.org) is a notation methodology for representing objects. So you need to consider whether you want to think of the object as your table, or a record in the table. Your table may be too big to represent as an object. Most people represent records, or small record collections as objects in JSON.

Here's a good discussion of it: http://mike.bailey.net.au/2011/02/json-with-ruby-and-rails/

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have :-

```
@country = Country.all
```

and you to convert @country data into json.

```
 json_converted_data = JSON.parse(@country)
```

I guess this will work

Comment: this will not work...JSON.parse is a javascript call from the clientside...where as /@country is in a rails collection on the server side...it would work if /@country was a js variable containing the content of a json response